# Does Excel VBA WorksheetFunction need to use a select to be on the proper worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code, but I have to select the worksheet otherwise the WorksheetFunction will return an error:

```
Function Find_Allocation_Acct_Row_Number(allocation_acct As String, allocation_cc As String)
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim CC_row As Integer
Dim search_rng As Range

Set WS = Sheets(allocation_cc)
WS.Select

Set search_rng = WS.Range("E1:E2000")

CC_row = WS.Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(allocation_acct,search_rng, 0)

Find_Allocation_Acct_Row_Number = CC_row + 4
End Function
```

How can I select the right range on the right worksheet without using the Select command?

To be clear, I will ALWAYS find the value.  I just need to return the row so I can create a range from it.

I have tried a number of different ways to change the "search_rng" to different variables or expressions of Range but no luck.

The error I am getting is:

```
Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the Match property of the WorksheetFunction class
```

Comment: What's the error message? Note - better to pass the function a worksheet object than a string representing the name. And also better to use `Long` instead of `Integer`. And be explicit - add `As Long` to the end of the function declaration.

Comment: You do not need the `WS` on the `Match`  The `Search_rng` has the worksheet as part of the variable.  You should not need the `WS.Select`

Comment: If you are getting an error it is because when the value is not found in the search range an error is produced that stops the code.

Comment: ^^ You need error handling to account for the possibility of no match.

Comment: This value will always be there.  I'm pretty amateur at coding this, but I will get a specific account (say 0001) and then it will be on a different line depending on how many other lines we are getting.  This returns the row that I need.  So the object to find is there - the issue is that I THINK it is on a different worksheet when it tries to search.

Comment: If you are looking for `0001` it may be as simple as the lookup is a number that is formatted to show the lead `0`s and not a text string.  If you try to match a text string `0001` to `1` that is formatted `0000` it will not find a match.

Comment: @ScottCraner I did a bunch of testing using lengths, setting the two equal on the spreadsheet, Immediate window variable testing, testing for types, etc - they are identical strings as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Vaslo the issue is then not with the code but the data, or the way you are calling the function.

Comment: The `Set WS = Sheets(allocation_cc)` is suspect - because there's an implicit `ActiveWorkbook` - you need to qualify the workbook. This is why I proposed passing a `Worksheet` object instead of the worksheet name as a string.

Comment: @BigBen So this is part of a larger program.  Basically I use this to get the row number.  There is another function that gets the allocation tab by using a cell value.  I think what you are saying is just to go into a higher scope, get the worksheet name and save it in that scope and then pass it to the functions that need it?

Comment: Sorry if my comment wasn't clear. I meant that you should have `Function Find...(ByVal allocationWs as Worksheet, ByVal allocation_cc as String`. Pass the function a fully qualified worksheet object, not a string of the worksheet name. In other words, that other function should return a worksheet object that you can pass to this one.

Comment: @BigBen I believe you are right that it is not great handling of Worksheet Object handling.  I ran into another problem while doing this which I'll post as a separate question but in short I had to add my WS object to the two "Cells" which were called.  Seems to be working now but I cannot with certainty understand why that was happening because I clearly don't know the passing of objects as well as I'd like.

Answer (score 1):

If the match is not found it will kick out an error and stop the code.  If we late bind the match and send the result to a variant we can test for the error:

```
Function Find_Allocation_Acct_Row_Number(allocation_acct As String, allocation_cc As String) As Long
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Set WS = Worksheets(allocation_cc)

    Dim search_rng As Range
    Set search_rng = WS.Range("E1:E2000")

    Dim CC_row As Variant
    CC_row = Application.Match(allocation_acct, search_rng, 0)

    If Not IsError(CC_row) Then
        Find_Allocation_Acct_Row_Number = CC_row + 4
    Else
        Find_Allocation_Acct_Row_Number = -1
    End If
End Function
```

Now if a match cannot be found it will return `-1`

Comment: Sorry I added above the Error should not occur because this value will ALWAYS be in there.  The line will simply differ.

Comment: @Vaslo *never* assume the error will not occur. Because - it will, Murphy's law.

Comment: Well, I believe in the abundance of caution and can add the recommendation, but if it errors out when I know my value is there, it isn't solving my problem unfortunately.